# Nested divs with text indentation issue in Chrome/IE

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, text-indent

I am having problems with nested divs in Chrome and IE, whereas in Firefox it works fine.

I have two style attribute (text-indent and margin-top) set in the outer div. The "display" style of inner div is set to block. So, ideally the content after the inner div should appear in a new line without any indentation. It appears so in Firefox, whereas in Chrome/IE it appears with text indentation! Based on this behaviour if I assume that this content fragment (from "remaining text" shown below) inherits the style attribute of the corresponding div, that is not the case too; because, only the text-indent is inheritted and the margin-top is not! Could you please help me to understand on where I am doing wrong?

By the way here is the html fragment:

```
<div style="text-indent:50px; margin-top:100px">
Initial text in outer div. More text typed here. Still more text typed here. More and more text typed here. Still more text typed here just to fill the content so that the para wraps to more than one line. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text.

<div style="text-indent:0px;">Text in inner div. More text typed here. Still more text typed here. More and more text typed here. Still more text typed here just to fill the content so that the para wraps to more than one line. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text.</div>

remaining text in outer div. More text typed here. Still more text typed here. More and more text typed here. Still more text typed here just to fill the content so that the para wraps to more than one line. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text. More filler text.
</div>
```

Thanks
Srikanth

Answer (score 0):

The browsers are probably applying default styles to the elements.  Try explicitly setting `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to the elements in addition to setting your own custom margins.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But, I wont be able to do it, because there is no tag there! The text from "remaining" till the end of div is not wrapped in any tag, but somehow it behaves like a separate div in Chrome and in IE, whereas it works fine in FF.

Comment: You should consider wrapping those other lines of text in a block element like <p> or <div> and that may solve the inconsistency in browsers.